# Updating the value of another model in Django Models

Tags: django, django-models

I cannot find a way to update the value of 'no' in Class A from Class B in Django Models

```
class A(models.Model):
   no = models.IntegerField()

class B(models.Model):
   a = models.ForeignKey(A)
   def UpdateNo(self)
     #update no of class A
```

How to update 'no' field from

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain the object with `self.a`, and then alter and save the object, like:

```
class A(models.Model):
    no = models.IntegerField()

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

    def UpdateNo(self):
        my_a = self.a   # fetch the related A object in my_a
        my_a.no = 1234  # update the no field of that object
        my_a.save()     # save the update to the database
```

A `ForeignKey` will fetch *lazily* related objects, so `self.a` will contain the related `A` object. We thus then can handle it like we can handle any model object.